# alpine:3.14 docker libtls.so.20 conflict

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, libressl

So I am running into an error with the latest docker build from alpine. alpine:3.14.0 was released about a day ago and was trying to install libressl and libressl-dev and both seem to fail with the error below. My work around at the moment was to build using the alpine:3.12.0 as 3.12.0 seems to not have libretls installed. Although I would like to know how to fix this. I tried to remove libretls but that didn't work (error also below). Thanks

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289
$ docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/ash
/ # apk add libressl-dev
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing libressl3.3-libcrypto (3.3.3-r0)
(2/5) Installing libressl3.3-libssl (3.3.3-r0)
(3/5) Installing libressl3.3-libtls (3.3.3-r0)
ERROR: libressl3.3-libtls-3.3.3-r0: trying to overwrite usr/lib/libtls.so.20 owned by libretls-3.3.3-r0.
ERROR: libressl3.3-libtls-3.3.3-r0: trying to overwrite usr/lib/libtls.so.20.0.3 owned by libretls-3.3.3-r0.
(4/5) Installing pkgconf (1.7.4-r0)
(5/5) Installing libressl-dev (3.3.3-r0)
Executing busybox-1.33.1-r2.trigger
1 error; 41 MiB in 19 packages
/ #
/ # apk info libretls
libretls-3.3.3-r0 description:
port of libtls from libressl to openssl

libretls-3.3.3-r0 webpage:
https://git.causal.agency/libretls/

libretls-3.3.3-r0 installed size:
84 KiB
/ #
/ # apk del libretls
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
World updated, but the following packages are not removed due to:
  libretls: busybox alpine-baselayout apk-tools

OK: 6 MiB in 14 packages
/ # exit
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[this](https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12763#note_163217) is the upstream issue. Downgrading to alpine 3.13 works for now until the issue is fixed.
Normally docker images support fixed alpine versions (thanks to MrGlass comment). For example

```
python:3-alpine -> python:3-alpine3.13
php:7.4-fpm-alpine -> php:7.4-fpm-alpine3.13
```

Comment: great find was breaking my head

Comment: Perfect. If anyone here comes with the exact case I had, I was as simple as changing my projects base image from `python:3-alpine` to `python:3-alpine3.13`

Comment: I used this one `python:3.7-alpine3.13` and it worked well

Comment: I have been struggling with this for several days. Glad I found this. Unblocked in 30 seconds!

Comment: any resolution to this so we can move beyond alpine 3.13?